# @Value null on custom Kafka deserializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

PersonDeserializer is configured as the `value-deserializer` in application.yml, and in `deserialize` method, both `topicA` and `topicB` are null.

PersonDeserializer.java:

```
@Component
public class PersonDeserializer implements Deserializer<Person> {

    @Value("${app.topicA}")
    private String topicA;

    @Value("${app.topicB}")
    private String topicB;

    @Override
    public Person deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        // topicA == null, topicB == null
        // ...
    }

    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When specified in the `application.yml`, Kafka creates the objects, not Spring. Kafka knows nothing about `@Value`.

You need Spring to create the deserializer instead, and inject it directly into the consumer factory. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#serdes).

> **Important**
>
> Only simple configuration can be performed with properties; for more advanced configuration (such as using a custom ObjectMapper in the serializer/deserializer), you should use the producer/consumer factory constructors that accept a pre-built serializer and deserializer. For example, with Spring Boot, to override the default factories:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Foo, Bar> kafkaConsumerFactory(KafkaProperties properties,
    JsonDeserializer customDeserializer) {

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties.buildConsumerProperties(),
        customDeserializer, customDeserializer);
}

@Bean
public ProducererFactory<Foo, Bar> kafkaProducerFactory(KafkaProperties properties,
    JsonSserializer customSerializer) {

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties.buildProducerProperties(),
        customSerializer, customSerializer);
}
```